# Alterar valor LABEL por JQuery ou Javascript não funciona em ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Uso essa função JS no ASP.net:

```
function habilitado(){
    var b = document.getElementById('<%= Label4.ClientID %>').value = "Habilitado";
}
```

Eu a chamo assim no codebehind. O valor do label deveria ser alterado, mas isso não acontece. Alguém pode ajudar?

Obs: Já tentei usar `$(document).ready(function()` no começo, e mesmo assim não funciona.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "teste", "<script language=\"javascript\">habilitado();</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "teste", "<script type='text/javascript'>habilitado();</script>", true);
```

Comment: Quando você carrega a página no navegador, o Javascript gerado fica desse jeito mesmo? Já verificou se a primeira string (`'<%= Label4.ClientID %>'`) foi substituída pelo ID da label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A opção `value` não é aplicável para labels. Tente trocar por `innerHTML`. Assim:

`document.getElementById('<%= Label4.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Habilitado";`

Answer (score 1):

Com jQuery pode ser feito assim:

```
$('#<%= Label4.ClientID %>').html("Conteúdo novo...");
```

Answer (score 1):

O `.value` do javascript só tem utilidade em elementos `<input />` sendo que deve ser utilizado o .innerHTML quando quer se obter/modificar o conteúdo interno de algum elemento, como por exemplo em div's, label's e span's.

Fontes:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp